# How do I attach a sound file to a button on click

Tags: android, animation, javasound

How do I attach an MP3 sound file to a button on click method.  I already have an invisibility on the same button how can I change the invisibility to a scale to zero along with sound file

```
mainButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button button = (Button) v;
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Are you sure [scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scale) is the correct tag? Which platform is this for? Android?

Comment: Ye s android. Sorry sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use MediaPlayer for that

First place your mp3 file in the raw folder of your project, then on your activity create a method like this:

```
   fun playSong(){
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_mp3_file)
        mediaPlayer.start()
   }
```

call this method inside your click Listener, and then `mediaPlayer.stop()` to stop playing.

I would suggest checking the [mediaplayer docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer) to see all available methods/properties of it, I think it's the simplest way of playing audio on Android.

Also check the [resources guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) on android docs to make sure you have what you need to import your mp3 file in your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Not sure where programatically to place this could you show me the entire code and syntax including onclicklistener syntax

Comment: As I said in my comment, place this method in you activity, then call it from inside your click listener onClick method

Comment: Not programming in kotlin

Comment: Java equivalent - `private void playSong(){
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.your_mp3_file);
        mediaPlayer.start();
   }` the rest stays as the same